# Getting errors using moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'm using LaTeX with TeXWorks (MiKTex) where I've found an issue. I'm helping my fiancé Writing her CV. I want to use `moderncv` package, but it does not work. Using the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{grey} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\address{My address}
\mobile{000}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
 Hej
\end{document}
```

LaTeX complains about *awesomefonttwo*. I'm not sure where this comes from (I myself haven't specified to use awesomefonttwo, but from what I've read its somehow comes with the package moderncv). Trying to find a solution to this, I've read that one can add:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

This adds another error though; that I must use *lualatex* or *xelatex*.

I've downloaded the moderncv folder. I have my .tex file for the CV inside the moderncv folder (it said that the moderncv.cls and moderncv.sty must be contained in the folder where the .tex file is, although I haven't found a file called moderncv.sty).

Could somebody please shed some light into this?

Regards,

Comment: Does your system have a recent (July of this year) version of `fontawesome` installed?

Comment: I tried to use \usepackage{fontawesome} but nothing happens. It usually comes a prompt which asks if you want to install the package or not. So I guess its installed. Trying to find where it is so I can see version.

Comment: Don't put you .tex file in a directory of the distribution! For fontawesome, install the latest version. Fontawesometwo and the like are special versions of fontawesome in type 1 format that you can use with pdflatex (normally, fontwesome is an opentype font, and it can't be used by pdflatex), and they were introduced in the latest version (beginning of this month) of the fontawaesome package.

Comment: @Bernard I downloaded the moderncv folder into my "work folder" and then put my CV .tex files into that one. Perhaps thats the wrong approach? I will try to find the fontawesome download!

Comment: TeX knows  perfectly where to find the moderncv files of the distribution, you don't have  to have it it in the working folder. Install moderncv and fontawesome with MiKTeX Package Manager (admin version if you want al users can use it).

Comment: @Bernard I've looked into my MiKTeX Package Manager and I saw that both awesomefont and moderncv were installed there, and they were both "packaged on" (I assume thats the time of the latest update on the installed version?) in the beginning of august. August 4 in both cases

Comment: Then they are not the problem. Could you post a minimal (non-)working example to test what's happening?

Comment: @Bernard Im guessing I've misinterpreted the comment in the .tex file I've seen for the CV file (took it from Internet) that the moderncv.sty and moderncv.cls files should be in the same folder as the .tex file, based on your earlier comment then? Can that be the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27479/discussion-between-bernard-and-gustav-danell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see several missunderstandings in your question.

1. With windows you have the standard directory `c:/documents`. 
   Create there an sub directory, for example `latex`.  There you can write your own tex code, for example `mwe.tex`.  You can open and compile this file `c:/documents/latex/mwe.tex` with your editor, TeXWorks, TeXnicCenter, WinEDT etc.
2. Class `moderncv` should you only install with the installing or updating or package manager program of MiKTeX. Theese programs knew better that you where and how to install class `moderncv`.
3. After correct installation/update of MiKTeX you can compile your file `mwe.tex`, because now MiKTeX is able to find and run class `moderncv.cls` and related files.
4. `moderncv` has been changed and uses now font `awesomefont` to display symbols for a telephone etc.  After the first change there was a bug resulting with the message about `awesomefonttwo`.  That bug was fixed.  To get no warning messages use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile:  `lualatex mwe.tex`.
5. If you want to compile with `pdflatex` use the following modified MWE (see my changes marked with `<======` in the code).

Changed `mwe.tex` to be compiled with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{grey} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\name{Joe}{Doe}
\address{My address}
\mobile{000}

\moderncvicons{marvosym} % marvosym awesome % for pdflatex! <===========
\setlength{\footskip}{37pt} % no more \footskip warning <===============


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
 Hej
\end{document}
```

It compiles on my current MiKTeX 2.9 with `moderncv 2.0.0` with only three warnings (caused in another bug in `moderncv` which has to be corrected by the author of the class) and no errors.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. This solved the issue, or specifically, I got even more errors trying to update MikTeX. However, uninstalling it and subsequentially installing a new MikTeX version solved the issue. Finally I can update my CV!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your MWE is not working even if fontawesome is properly detected. This snippet works:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{grey} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\firstname{Douche}
\lastname{Bag} 
\address{My address}
\mobile{000}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
 Hej
\end{document}
```

The solution to your problem probably is in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263611/75026) answer.

I would be very interested to hear back from you and see if this resolved your issue.