# FontAwesome source file not found

Tags: moderncv, fontawesome

I am trying to modify a CV I created on my old notebook. I have a fresh install of MiKTeX and TeXstudio on my new system, but my CV won't compile. I am using PDFLaTeX to compile. Originally, I created my CV from the built in `moderncv` template. Strangely enough it compiles if I choose the `classic` and not the `casual` option but the font doesn't really seem different.

> Trying to make PK font FontAwesome--fontawesometwo at 600 DPI...
>
> Running miktex-makemf.exe...
>
> miktex-makemf: The FontAwesome--fontawesometwo source file could not
>   be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...
>
> miktex-makepk
>
> : PK font FontAwesome--fontawesometwo could not be created.

What I have tried so far:

- Copying the `fonts` folder from my old system's MiKTeX installation
- Running `initexmf --mkmaps` and `initexmf --update-fndb`
- Reinstalling the font with the package manager
- I tried the solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260781/85611), didn't work.

I am using Windows 10, MiKTeX 2.9, and TeXstudio 2.9.4.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
\moderncvstyle{casual}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            personal data
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{first name}
\familyname{family name}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}         % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted; the "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\mobile{mobile number}                          % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\phone{phone number}                           % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\begin{document}
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Description}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: For others to help, is it a good idea to provide a small but full document that others can copy to their own system and test. For example here we cannot see how you have asked for FontAwesome.

Comment: I am working on it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you try running `\updmap` in an administrator console?

Comment: Runs just fine with TeX Live 15.

Comment: @Bernard Yes. The first time I tried compiling with `classic` instead of `casual` it didn't work and it had the same problem but with a different font. Then I ran `initexmf --mkmaps` and `initexmf --update-fndb` which solved the problem. Sadly it does not help with FontAwesome.

Comment: @daleif I will try using TeX Live instead of MiKTeX then I guess.

Comment: @spinakker, there is a reason why I tend to recommend it, also on windows. One caveat thought, you will need to reinstall it once a year.

Comment: Alright I sort of fixed it. I downgraded the modernCV package to the same version I used to create the document in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I have no problem with moderncv on MiKTeX…

Comment: Compile `\documentclass{article} 
\pdfmapfile{=fontawesome.map} 
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faFlag
\end{document}` and if it works show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer http://pastebin.com/AMkrcMnw

Is this what we are looking for?

Comment: Looks fine, everything is there. Now run on a command line (in your user account) `updmap`. Comment `\pdfmapfile{=fontawesome.map}` in the example and try again. Does it work?

Comment: I got the same error I have been getting in my CV!

Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/Q0kzuLMM .

So I guess I should include that magic line `\pdfmapfile{=fontawesome.map}` in the modernCV template as well?

Comment: `\pdfmapfile{=fontawesome.map}` will certainly help. But it is curious that `updmap` doesn't add the map file for you. It looks as if the map wasn't added to updmap.cfg but on my system there is no problem.  Can you run `updmap --verbose > updmap.log`  and then show me the created updmap.log?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer http://pastebin.com/x8RegKdc

Comment: Well for some reason fontawesome.map is not in the cfg. Open one of the `updmap.cfg` mentioned in the log and add `Map fontawesome.map`. Then run updmap again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Alright it works. Wonder how things went wrong in the first place.. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: For me running `updmap` as admin didn't solve the situation. TeX Live 16.

Comment: don't know why, but `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` did it for me ;)

Comment: I encountered this issue today. The moderncv package comes with individual .sty files for each style (classic, casual, etc.). You have to ensure that these files (or at least the one corresponding to the style you want to use) is in the same directory where your .tex file is.

Comment: On Debian 10, I simply needed to install `texlive-fonts-extra`.

Comment: The question was about MikTeX on Windows, so a Debian solution does not really answer the question. It could be useful though for other people that experience this problem on Debian or derivatives, provided that they have installed LaTeX with `apt` packages and not by running the TeX Live installer.

Answer (score 12):

The newest version of the modernCV template somehow doesn't mesh well with the rest of my system. Downgrading to an older version of the template solved the problem.

Using TeX Live 15 should also work.

---

**Actual solution:** Add the line `Map fontawesome.map` to the `updmap.cfg` file.
Many thanks to @UlrikeFischer for walking me trough it.

Comment: Thanks @spinakker, where can I find this `updmap.cfg` file?

Comment: In a Command Prompt window, run `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`

Comment: Wow, this actually fixed it, I can't believe it. Thank you. I opened a command prompt window, typed `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` , then the file updmap.cfg opened automatically in notepad and I added the line `Map fontawesome.map`, then back at the command prompt I typed `initexmf --mkmaps`, and then I was able to compile my CV successfully (using TexStudio). (I followed the instructions for updating updmap.cfg that I found [here](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html).)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on my system...the FontAwesome seems to be called only by the "casual" style file, and not the "classic", which is why one can get the "classic" to compile and not the "casual" style. I would just recommend that you use the classic style, or whichever compiles for you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it as suggested [here](https://github.com/xdanaux/fontawesome-latex/issues/8#issuecomment-241013241)  :

1. open the miktex package manager (admin) and uninstall fontawesome
2. install fontawesome with non admin package manager

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pdflatex`, here is one solution, which edits the `moderncv` style files. (Not sure how this will persist on update of your latex distribution)

The `moderncv.cls` config files define three styles of icons:

1. *`awesome`*  (moderncviconsawesome.sty)
2. *`marvosym`* (moderncviconsmarvosym.sty)
3. *`letters`*  (moderncviconsletters.sty)

The *`awesome`* style is loaded in most options for `\moderncvstyle` (except `classic`, which loads *`marvosym`* and `oldstyle`, which loads *`letters`*).
The *`awesome`* style does not work with `pdflatex`, but I honestly can't tell the difference between this and *`marvosym`*. So, my solution is to:

#### Replace `\moderncvicons{awesome}` with `\moderncvicons{marvosym}` in all style files:

`moderncvstyle*.sty`, where `* = {banking,casual,fancy}` (and `oldstyle` too if you prefer).

Not sure why `awesome` is the default, given the compatibility issues, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about a latex distribution update, because the missing Map file entry would probably be fixed by any bigger update. (Also, I wouldn't expect any `moderncv` updates anymore) Anyway, is there a reason why you suggest changing the style file instead of changing the icon style *after* the style is loaded? (I mean adding `\moderncvicons{...}` after `\modercvstyle{...}`) Then you would not have to worry about updates reverting your changes and your document will behave consistently on other systems.