# Problems with Fontawesome on MikTex

Tags: fonts, fontawesome, miktex-update

I installed Fontawesome using the MikTex Package Manager. I tried to update the database, using the command :

```
Start > Programs > MiKTeX > Maintenance > Settings > General > Refresh FNDB
```

Then I updated the `updmap.cfg` file with the fontawesome entry, used the updmap command ([output](https://pastebin.com/Ff55LqvC)), but when I try to create my PDF, I still get an error message:

```
pdflatex.exe> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file FontAwesome--fontawesomethree): Font FontAwes
pdflatex.exe> ome--fontawesomethree at 657 not found
```

Here is my installation: [Fontawesome installation](https://pastebin.com/XeSnxmqw)
What am I missing?

Comment: You probably need to run `updmap` on a command line.

Comment: I already did (in the link "output") above, I put the output from the command. It seems to run OK

Comment: Make a small hello-world document and compile it with pdflatex. At the end of the log-file it loads a pdftex.map. What is the path of this pdftex.map?

Comment: Hello, here is the path: `C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map`

Comment: Here is the pdflatex output:  https://pastebin.com/yeCaGGWV

Comment: In the directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\tfm\public\fontawesome`is the file:  `FontAwesome--fontawesomethree.tfm`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I saw your solution in this question (add the 
`\pdfmapfile{=fontawesome.map}`) : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263595/fontawesome-source-file-not-found and now it works! Do I always need to inform this map? Thanks!

Comment: Your hello-world document uses `C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map`. Your updmap call wrote a different file `C:\Users\general\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex.map`.

Comment: Did you run updmap in your user account in a normal command line without admin rights?

Comment: Ok, I see. I used the other user "general", because this account has administrative rights. I thought it would be valid for everyone.

Comment: No user settings can overwrite defaults set by the admin. If the admin set the background of your monitor to gray and you then as user add a picture the picture wins.

Comment: I ran updmap with my user now and now everything is fine! Thank you @UlrikeFischer!