# Trouble with fontawesome after upgrade

Tags: fonts, miktex, fontawesome

I just upgraded my system to `miktex-20.6.29-x64` (followed by performing update) and then suddenly package `fontawesome` doesn't work anymore.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \faFloppyO
\end{document}
```

Above code produced error message

```
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information 
to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\Puji\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log
        
Process exited with error(s)
```

and the logfile contains this lines at the bottom

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file FontAwesome--fontawesometwo): Font FontAwesom
e--fontawesometwo at 720 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368902/problems-with-fontawesome-on-miktex

Answer (score 0):

Running `updmap` fixed the the problem. Case closed.

Comment: You should explain why `updmap` works.